# Neo4j console won't start

Tags: java, neo4j, freebsd

I'm currently trying to use WikiNet with Neo4j. I succeed to install the good version of the openjdk7 for Neo4j on my FreeBSD 9.2.
But when I did 
`./neo4j start
WARNING: Max 11095 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [57367]... waiting for server to be ready..................... OK.
http://localhost:7474/ is ready.
$ ./neo4j status
Neo4j Server is not running`

I have this message

And when I try to do

```
./neo4j console
WARNING: Max 11095 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
11:51:24,123 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
11:51:24,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
11:51:24,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/usr/home/freeant/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar!/logback.xml]
11:51:24,238 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@195ee3d - URL [jar:file:/usr/home/freeant/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
11:51:24,517 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
11:51:24,531 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil@4be9a8 - Failed to get local hostname java.net.UnknownHostException: root: root
    at java.net.UnknownHostException: root: root
    at  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil.getLocalHostName(ContextUtil.java:32)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.ContextUtil.addHostNameAsProperty(ContextUtil.java:41)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction.begin(ConfigurationAction.java:56)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:276)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:148)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:130)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:157)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:143)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:106)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:56)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at  at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:121)
    at  at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractFileConfiguration.<init>(AbstractFileConfiguration.java:154)
    at  at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:252)
    at  at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.loadPropertiesConfig(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:142)
    at  at org.neo4j.server.configuration.PropertyFileConfigurator.<init>(PropertyFileConfigurator.java:76)
    at  at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.createConfigurator(Bootstrapper.java:193)
    at  at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:84)
    at  at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: root
    at  at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at  at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at  at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
    at  ... 30 common frames omitted
11:51:24,531 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
11:51:24,558 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
11:51:24,844 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
11:51:25,033 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
11:51:25,033 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
11:51:25,035 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:51:25,041 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@d3d0d4 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

2014-03-16 10:51:25.672+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
2014-03-16 10:51:37.771+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully started database
2014-03-16 10:51:40.657+0000 INFO  [API] Starting HTTP on port :7474 with 10 threads available
2014-03-16 10:51:41.341+0000 INFO  [API] Enabling HTTPS on port :7473
2014-03-16 10:51:42.265+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted discovery module at [/]
2014-03-16 10:51:42.289+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted REST API at [/db/data/]
2014-03-16 10:51:42.307+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted management API at [/db/manage/]
2014-03-16 10:51:42.322+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted webadmin at [/webadmin]
2014-03-16 10:51:42.326+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted Neo4j Browser at [/browser]
2014-03-16 10:51:42.595+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
2014-03-16 10:51:42.774+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/browser] from [browser]
11:51:42.777 [main] WARN  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@242c99{/,null,null} contextPath ends with /
11:51:42.777 [main] WARN  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Empty contextPath
11:51:42.783 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.0.5.v20130815
11:51:44.152 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@868079{/,null,AVAILABLE}
11:51:44.678 [main] INFO  o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /webadmin, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
11:51:44.715 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@c8f692{/webadmin,jar:file:/usr/home/freeant/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.0.1-static-web.jar!/webadmin-html,AVAILABLE}
11:51:46.760 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@f99d1b{/db/manage,null,AVAILABLE}
11:51:48.063 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3d2891{/db/data,null,AVAILABLE}
11:51:48.108 [main] INFO  o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /browser, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
11:51:48.111 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@ecf90a{/browser,jar:file:/usr/home/freeant/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-browser-2.0.1.jar!/browser,AVAILABLE}
11:51:48.606 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@242c99{/,null,AVAILABLE}
11:51:48.641 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@122dabd keys=-1 selected=-1: java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:130) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:68) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.doStart(SelectorManager.java:338) ~[jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:177) [jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:82) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:259) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:303) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:350) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:173) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:405) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:185) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
11:51:48.644 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@d786d2: java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:130) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:68) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.doStart(SelectorManager.java:338) ~[jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:177) ~[jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:82) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:259) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:303) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:350) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:173) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:405) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:185) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
11:51:48.646 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED ServerConnector@134a0a3{HTTP/1.1}{localhost:7474}: java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:130) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:68) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.doStart(SelectorManager.java:338) ~[jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:177) ~[jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:82) ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:259) ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81) ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:303) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:350) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:173) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:405) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:185) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
11:51:50.787 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector@829abf keys=-1 selected=-1: java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:130) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:68) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.doStart(SelectorManager.java:338) ~[jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:177) [jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:82) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:259) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:303) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:350) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:173) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:405) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:185) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
11:51:50.789 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@7db06f: java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:130) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:68) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.doStart(SelectorManager.java:338) ~[jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:177) ~[jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:82) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:259) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:303) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:350) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:173) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:405) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:185) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
11:51:50.791 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED ServerConnector@1ca51eb{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{localhost:7473}: java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
java.io.IOException: Function not implemented
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollCreate(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.<init>(EPollArrayWrapper.java:130) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:68) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager$ManagedSelector.doStart(SelectorManager.java:338) ~[jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:177) ~[jetty-io-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:82) ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:259) ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81) ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:303) [jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) [jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:350) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:173) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:405) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:185) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
11:51:50.792 [main] WARN  o.e.j.u.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@1c8401f: MultiException[java.io.IOException: Function not implemented, java.io.IOException: Function not implemented]
org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:286) ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:350) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:173) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:405) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:185) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
2014-03-16 10:51:50.795+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474], reason [MultiException[java.io.IOException: Function not implemented, java.io.IOException: Function not implemented]]
2014-03-16 10:51:50.799+0000 DEBUG [API] 
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: MultiException[java.io.IOException: Function not implemented, java.io.IOException: Function not implemented]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:218) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: MultiException[java.io.IOException: Function not implemented, java.io.IOException: Function not implemented]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:354) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.start(Jetty9WebServer.java:173) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:405) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:185) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:286) ~[jetty-server-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69) ~[jetty-util-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]
    at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.startJetty(Jetty9WebServer.java:350) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
2014-03-16 10:51:50.838+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
$
```

It doesn't work

Can you help me?
Thanks a lot
A.H

Comment: It's not finding your logging configuration files. This question is specific to your personal environment and your failure to configure that environment correctly. We are not going to visit your home, rummage through your files and try to figure out what you did wrong. Short answer: misconfiguration problems are too specific and do not belong on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD is not a supported platform for running Neo4j.

Based on http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?9198-server-core-failure-java-io-IOException-Function-not-implemented, you might try to add to `conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf`:

```
wrapper.java.additional=-Djava.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider=sun.nio.ch .PollSelectorProvider
```

Due to lack of having FreeBSD locally, I could not verify if that really helps - but worth a try

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does work for me. It's very nice :-) Have a nice day